# BASH using grep and awk inside a variable

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, grep

```
bash-3.2$ FNAME=$1
bash-3.2$ OLD_NO=$(grep "_version=" | awk -F '"' '{print $12}' $FNAME)
```

Line 2 does not appear to be working for me. Am I not closing/quoting it correctly? 
It seems to hang

Updated the script to reflect below suggestions

```
echo $OLD_NO
OLD_NO=$(grep '_version=' "$FNAME" | awk -F '"' '{print $12}')
#Get the version of the
echo "What do you want to update release number to?"
REPLACEMENT="_version="$NEW_NO
echo $REPLACEMENT
sed -i ''s/$OLD_NO/$REPLACEMENT/g'' $FNAME
```

~

get a new error

```
bash-3.2$ ./vu reader.xml 

What do you want to update release number to?
_version=
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Works in bash though

```
bash-3.2$ grep _version market_rules_cd.reader.xml | awk -F '"' '{print $12}'
```

14.8.21.1

Comment: What's the need for `$1` at the last?

Comment: `grep` is waiting for its input on standard input; I think you just want to put `$FNAME` after the `grep`, not the `awk`.

Comment: You have changed your question radically since I've answered. (e.g. including my answer in your code now). I've rolled back those changes. Please ask a new question if you need additional help

Comment: Where do you set `NEW_NO` in your script? You ask a question, yet you never read any input and don't set `NEW_NO`.

Answer (score 2):

The line hangs because `grep '_version='` will blocking wait on stdin since you didn't passed a file name argument. To stop it from hanging pass the file name to grep, not to awk. awk will then process grep's output:

```
OLD_NO=$(grep '_version=' "$FNAME" | awk -F '"' '{print $12}')
```

---

Btw: The job can be done with `awk` only, you don't need grep:

```
OLD_NO=$(awk -F '"' '/_version=/ {print $12}' "$FNAME")
```

Note that awk programs having the following form:

```
condition { action }  [; more of them ]
```

You can omit the condition if the action should apply to every line (this is widely used), however in this case you can use a regex condition to restrict the action only to lines containing `_version=`:

```
/_version=/ { print $12 }
```

Comment: I think `FNAME` is the name of a file to search, not the actual value to search.

Comment: this brings back no results if I use it in the shell

Comment: does not work                                                               awk -F '"' '/_version=/ {print $12}' filename